# Programmatically get/set JMeter variable when extending JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am building a custom config element by extending JMeter SDK. I have achieved most of my desired functionality. Last piece is to set a computed value to a JMeter variable so that it can be used in HTTP Samplers.
I looked at existing components implementation - Test Plan and User Defined Variables, but could not figure steps to set a variable value. `Argument` and `Arguments` classes are the closest I could get, but not answering the question.

In my config element, I am extending `AbstractConfigGui` to create GUI components and `AbstractTestElement` to glue UI and Data.

My code is not available on public domain, but can share snippets if required for further clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [JMeterVariables](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/150a2753b4bb055c678965a1ec9a66af3362345d/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.java) class

> Class which defines JMeter variables.

You can get them from context:

```
JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
```